# JavaFX: Only update binding after all dependencies are updated?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

```
private final Property<BigDecimal> a = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>();
private final Property<BigDecimal> b = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>();

private ObjectBinding<BigDecimal> c = new ObjectBinding<BigDecimal>() {
    {
        super.bind(a, b);
    }

    @Override
    protected BigDecimal computeValue() {
        return a.getValue().add(b.getValue());
    }
};
public BigDecimal getC() { return c.getValue(); }
```

I have two properties and a value that is bound to the sum of those properties. I have one thread viewing `c` and calling `getC()` when it is changed, and another thread that is supposed to update `a` & `b`. I would like the update to `a` & `b` to be atomic; I do not want the value of `c` to be observed when `a` has been updated but `b` has not.

The solution I came up with is to have a third property that `c`'s binding uses as a flag to signal update completion, something like

```
update(a, 1);
update(b, 2);
update(updateComplete, true); // C is only computed at this point

private final Property<BigDecimal> a = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>();
private final Property<BigDecimal> b = new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>();
private final IntegerProperty updateComplete = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

private ObjectBinding<BigDecimal> c = new ObjectBinding<BigDecimal>() {
    {
        super.bind(updateComplete);
    }

    @Override
    protected BigDecimal computeValue() {
        return a.getValue().add(b.getValue());
    }
};
public BigDecimal getC() { return c.getValue(); }
```

Is there a more idiomatic solution to this problem?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think properties are a good solution for communication between threads.  There are probably systems better suited to such tasks (such as [Actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/untyped-actors.html), [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and [javafx.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html)).

Comment: How are you managing synchronization between the threads? JavaFX properties are not thread-safe by design: I'm struggling to see how you would ensure liveness of `c` if it were updated (indirectly, by updating `a` and/or `b`) from a different thread than the one on which you were observing it.

Comment: @James_D Right. I'm trying to figure out the best way to manage that synchronization so that _interim values of `c`_—when `a` has been updated but `b` has not, or vice versa—are not observed. Viewing an older (valid) version of `c` is fine.

Comment: @jewelsea Yeah I see your point—I'd really like to be able to work this out though. It would be so nice to have the fields "just update" and have either an old value or a new one, you know?

Comment: @JohnDorian I was refering to liveness, though, rather than atomicity.

Comment: @James_D Ah my bad. Can you be more specific? Do you see this causing a deadlock/livelock/starvation issue?

Comment: You could investigate [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX), in particular its `EventStreams.combine` function and `Indicator` feature.  Those seem to be things that could assist in solving your update problem in a single threaded environment.  As ReactFX is built upon JavaFX properties, I don't think its written for use in multi-threaded environments.  So, I guess, apply it at your own risk in a multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, though I would not call it idiomatic ;), is to provide 2 different bindings to `c`. Both bindings would have the same `computeValue` method, but one of those binds to only `a` (or `b`, depending on your needs).

The thread viewing `c` would then get access to the binding, that updates only when one value changes.

```
private final ObjectBinding<BigDecimal> c              = new ObjectBinding<BigDecimal>()
                                                     {
                                                       {
                                                         super.bind( a, b );
                                                       }

                                                       @Override
                                                       protected BigDecimal computeValue()
                                                       {
                                                         return a.getValue().add( b.getValue() );
                                                       }
                                                     };

private final ObjectBinding<BigDecimal> cOnlyOnBChange = new ObjectBinding<BigDecimal>()
                                                     {
                                                       {
                                                         super.bind( b );
                                                       }

                                                       @Override
                                                       protected BigDecimal computeValue()
                                                       {
                                                         return a.getValue().add( b.getValue() );
                                                       }
                                                     };
```

See [full example](https://gist.github.com/flasheater/a375f3435a867290e1b8223ee89d1a4a).